# Getting random module seed in python from a given series?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I've been doing some digging about the library of babel online and wanted to replicate its core functionality but I have no idea where to begin other than the random module on python.
I understand that you can input a seed to it and it generates the same series over and over again. I wonder if there's a way to reverse this process wherein one would enter an array and get the seed out. I've been looking and there doesn't seem to be any leads. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** possible to get the `seed` that was used when generating a list of numbers using the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) module in Python.

I would suggest storing the seed that was initially used when generating the pseudo-random list, so you can infer it later on where needed.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea on how the library of babel does its searches then?

Comment: @TheWoodenPen No idea, sorry.